# How can I coalesce these IIS <httpRedirect> rules?

Tags: iis, web-config

My web config like this :

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
    <add wildcard="*/Find-a-Product" destination="https://mysubdomain.com/" />
    <add wildcard="*/Find-a-Product/" destination="https://mysubdomain.com/" />
    <add wildcard="*/find a Product" destination="https://mysubdomain.com/" />
    <add wildcard="*/find a Product/" destination="https://mysubdomain.com/" />
</httpRedirect>
```

I want to combine the four routes into 1 routes

How can I do it?

Comment: These are IIS redirects, not ASP.NET routes.

Comment: You should use IIS newer `<rewrite>` feature instead of the ancient (and inflexible) `<httpRedirect>` feature).

Comment: @Dai I directly edit in web.config. Can it be handled on web.config?

Comment: IIS’ `<rewrite>` is in web.config, yes. Search Microsoft’s documentation for “IIS URL Rewrite Module”.

Comment: @Dai Yeah but if I edit it directly on web.config it actually doesn't matter? Right

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doesn't matter".

Comment: @Dai I mean "it also works". So it's the same

Comment: How is the leading wildcard supposed to work? Please provide examples of input URLs (both those that *should* be redirected and those that shouldn't).

Comment: I've changed the title and tags of your question to remove references to C#, ASP.NET, and Sitecore as nothing you've posted has any relation at all to those.

Answer (score 0):

- The web.config file fragment that you posted shows that you are **not** using ASP.NET Routing to redirect `/Find-a-Product/` to another location - but in fact you are using IIS' built-in `<system.webServer><httpRedirect>` element.

  - The capabilities of `<httpRedirect>` are limited, as you're seeing.
- You should use IIS' URL Rewrite Module instead. Note this is an optional module but most Shared Web Hosts with IIS - and Azure App Services - have the module installed. Contact your host or ops people to see if it's available.

  - Despite the name "URL Rewrite", the module can be used to perform redirections too.
- Change your `<system.webServer><httpRedirect>` rules to `<system.webServer><rewrite>` as below.
- Regarding the `<match url="" />` element:

  - It uses a Regular Expression rather than simpler wildcard matching (though it does optionally support wildcard matching). It uses ECMAScript-standard Regular Expression syntax.
  - It is case-insensitive by default, so you don't need separate rules for `find-a-product` and `Find-A-Product`, for example.

    - Set `<match ignoreCase="false" />` for case-sensitive behaviour.
  - You do not specify a leading slash: it is implicit (so `<match url="foobar">` will match `https://example.com/foobar`).
- Note that Microsoft's documentation for the URL Rewrite module is a tad confusing, because documentation for both versions 1.1 and 2.0 is available, but the documentation is additive, i.e. the documentation for version 2.0 does not describe how to use the `<match` element because it's in the documentation for version 1.1, so the documentation for version 2.0 only covers new functionality added in version 2.0.

  - [So as far as you're concerned, just use the documentation for version 1.1 (even though you'll be using version 2.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Here is how you can implement the same redirection rules using IIS' URL Rewrite module:

It's unclear from your posting how the leading `*` in your wildcard patterns should match input request URIs, so here's two different match rules:

#### Match path components BEFORE `/find-a-product`:

If you want to redirect `https://example.com/foobar/find-a-product` to `https://mysubdomain.com` (without carrying-over any request path or querystring) then use this pattern:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
 <rule name="Redirect rule">
  <match url="^(.+)\/Find[\-\s]a[\-\s]Product\/" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysubdomain.com" />
 </rule>
</rewrite>
```

#### Don't match path components before `/find-a-product`:

If you want to redirect `https://example.com/find-a-product` to `https://mysubdomain.com` (without carrying-over any request path or querystring) then use this pattern:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
 <rule name="Redirect rule">
  <match url="^Find[\-\s]a[\-\s]Product\/" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysubdomain.com" />
 </rule>
</rewrite>
```

You can test these Regular Expressions on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this rule

```
  <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*/Find(\-|\s)a(\-|\s)Product(/)?" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysubdomain.com/" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
```

It work for all your conditions

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]